# Get the week number of the month from week number of the year

Tags: node.js

I am having a function that is returning the current week of the year  like 43,45 etc.

what I want is that to get it as week 1 week 2, for the current month .

P.S I only have current week of the year , Dont have date

Comment: Here's another answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9608670/334274

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get week of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280323/get-week-of-the-month)

Comment: I only have the week number of the year . this is a different issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'moment' module:

```
var moment = require('moment');

function foo(weekOfYear) {
    var dayOfMonth = moment().week(weekOfYear).date();
    var weekOfMonth = Math.ceil(dayOfMonth / 7);
    return weekOfMonth;
}

console.log(foo(1)) //1
console.log(foo(11)) //2
console.log(foo(12)) //3
console.log(foo(13)) //4
console.log(foo(14)) //1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var getWeekOfMonth = function(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay(),
        lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
        offsetDate = 7 - firstWeekday,
        daysAfterFirstWeek = lastDateOfMonth - offsetDate,
        weeksInMonth = Math.ceil(daysAfterFirstWeek / 7) + 1;

    var noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek = date.getDate() - offsetDate;
    if (noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek <= 0) {
        week = 1;
    } else if (noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek <= 7) {
        week = 2;
    } else if (noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek <= 14) {
        week = 3;
    } else if (noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek <= 21) {
        week = 4;
    } else if (weeksInMonth >= 5 && noOfDaysAfterRemovingFirstWeek <= 28) {
        week = 5;
    } else if (weeksInMonth === 6) {
        week = 6;
    }
    return week;
};
```

Comment: July 2016 has 6 week.