# How can I calculate the week of the month from week of the year?

Tags: python, pandas, date, calendar, time-series

I found a [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647513/get-the-week-number-of-the-month-from-week-number-of-the-year) solution but couldn't find a python one. I have a `DataFrame` that looks like:

```
   Year  Month      Week  numOfTrips
0  2011  July       30    2608
1  2011  August     31    6852
2  2011  August     32    8092
3  2011  August     33    7674
4  2011  August     34    7065
5  2011  August     35    3896
6  2011  September  35    4182
7  2011  September  36    7315
8  2011  September  37    8929
9  2011  September  38    7822
10 2011  September  39    6508
11 2011  October    39    1848
12 2011  October    40    9233
13 2011  October    41    7818
14 2011  October    42    7627
 .   .      .        .      .
 .   .      .        .      .
 .   .      .        .      .
```

I want to replace each week number by the week number of that month, how can I do this?

The result would look like:

```
   Year  Month      Week  numOfTrips
0  2011  July       5     2608
1  2011  August     1     6852
2  2011  August     2     8092
3  2011  August     3     7674
4  2011  August     4     7065
5  2011  August     5     3896
6  2011  September  1     4182
7  2011  September  2    7315
8  2011  September  3    8929
9  2011  September  4    7822
10 2011  September  5    6508
11 2011  October    1    1848
12 2011  October    2    9233
13 2011  October    3    7818
14 2011  October    4    7627
 .   .      .        .      .
 .   .      .        .      .
 .   .      .        .      .
```

Comment: Turn your data into `date` objects and then check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month

Comment: @DroidX86 you mean `datetime`? As in `df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Week)` ?

Comment: Yup try that. best way to get date info is to use actual `datetime` objects.

Comment: For anyone who is still trying to figure this out (like me): Those week numbers are "The week ordinal of the year", returned by [Series.dt.week](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively long and ugly solution that seems to work. If there are errors/bugs or a cleaner implementation, let me know.

**My approach**: using example  `2011  July    30    2608`

1. Get the weeks for the appropriate month in its respective year

```py
m = list(calendar.month_name).index('July') # turn month name into int
cal = calendar.Calendar()
weeks = cal.monthdatescalendar(2011,7) # get weeks for that month in the year
```

2. Get every week for the year you are dealing with. In our example its `2011`

`yr = cal.yeardatescalendar(2011, width=12)`

This code will fetch the year and store it in a 4D list: month-junk (in our case its 1 junk of 12 months), month, week, day. To query, do something like `yr[0][6][4][:]` for all the days on the 5th week of July. Because of this, the next step is to turn it into a 2D array which holds all the weeks.

```py
flat = [week for month in yr[0] for week in month]
dates = np.array(flat)
```

This `dates` will hold duplicates due to the way `cal.yeardatescalendar()` returns the list. We remove these:

```py
new_dates = []
for date in range(len(dates)):
    if not(np.array_equal(dates[date], np.array(dates[date-1]))):
        new_dates.append(dates[date])
```

At this point you have a 2D array of weeks which aligns with your week numbers. As in if you go [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html), and check week `30` for `2011`, you'll see it's the 5th week of July.

3. Next, we use the "correct" week-list array to query our week. Ex. week `30`

`the_week = new_dates[:][30]`

4. Finally, we see which week is our week in the month. When we get a match we know it's that week number.

```py
for week in range(len(weeks)): 
    if np.array_equal(the_week, np.array(weeks[week])):
        save_week_num = week+1
        print(save_week_num) # for our example it will print 5
```

Here it is in a function:

```py
def week_of_month(year, month, y_week):
    m = list(calendar.month_name).index(month) 
    cal = calendar.Calendar()
    weeks = cal.monthdatescalendar(year,m) 

    yr = cal.yeardatescalendar(year, width=12)
    flat = [week for month in yr[0] for week in month]
    dates = np.array(flat)

    new_dates = []
    for date in range(len(dates)):
        if not(np.array_equal(dates[date], np.array(dates[date-1]))):
            new_dates.append(dates[date])

    the_week = new_dates[:][y_week] # for 2013, replace this with: the_week = new_dates[:][y_week-1] 

    number = 0
    for week in range(len(weeks)):

        if np.array_equal(the_week, np.array(weeks[week])):

            save_week_num = week+1
            number = save_week_num

    return number
```

To test it on the `DataFrame` in the question run:

`df['Week'] = df.apply(lambda row: week_of_month(row.Year, row.Month, row.Week), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

### We can do the following:

First we convert your `Year` + `Week` to datetime using `pandas.to_datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Week'].astype(str) + '-1', format='%Y-%W-%w')
```

---

Then we define the function as mentioned in the comments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month):

```
from math import ceil

def week_of_month(dt):
    """ Returns the week of the month for the specified date.
    """

    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)

    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + first_day.weekday()

    return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```

---

Finally we apply the function to our `Date` column to get the `Weeknumber` of month:

```
df['Week'] = df['Date'].apply(week_of_month)
```

---

Which yields:

```
print(df)
   Year      Month  Week  numOfTrips       Date
0  2011       July     5        2608 2011-07-25
1  2011     August     1        6852 2011-08-01
2  2011     August     2        8092 2011-08-08
3  2011     August     3        7674 2011-08-15
4  2011     August     4        7065 2011-08-22
5  2011     August     5        3896 2011-08-29
6  2011  September     5        4182 2011-08-29
```

**Note** its not 100% accurate for the last row, because you dont have accurate dates. This would be 100% accurate if we had exact dates.

Comment: What do you mean exact dates? Week 35 of Sep, 2011 cannot be the 5th week if Week 39 of September is also the 5th week...

Comment: We extracted the `Date` column from `Year`  + `Week`. As you can see, our `Date` column can only be accurate on week level, not day level. Thats why it gives row 5 and row 6 the same date.

Comment: Ok, I interpreted your comment as in I don't have enough data to make an accurate calculation. Using `Month` in the equation I should be able to get the correct week. Which is what trying now.

Comment: Did you look at my answer? Then you might understand better what I mean